# How to add a new field to an existing MongoDB document using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have tried so many times to add new field to the existing MongoDB document but I failed. I tried following code to do the job but nothing happened.

Here is the **User** model.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Here is the code to add new field to the document.

```
const updateDocument = async () => {
  const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: "63eb30f466127f7a0f7a9b32" },
    {
      $set: { lastName: "syed" },
    }
  );
  console.log(updatedUser);
};

updateDocument();
```

**NOTE 1**: `lastName` field does not exist in the MongoDB document and in the `UserSchema`. I want to add that field to the MongoDB document.

**NOTE 2**: The same code works when I update the existing field inside the document but it does not work when adding new field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `strict:false` as an option to `findOneAndUpdate`.

According to the mongoose [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict):

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

```js
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "63eb30f466127f7a0f7a9b32" },
  {
    $set: { lastName: "syed" },
  },
  { strict: false }
);
```

An alternative way is to pass this parameter when you defined the schema:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true, strict: false }
);
```